# Wordpress comments not appearing in blog posts, likely because of Redux template. Could I fix this with a plugin that adds a comment form as a block?

Tags: plugins, posts, templates, comments, plugin-recommendation

Although I'm comfortable with coding I'm quite new to website building so please forgive me if I'm using clunky or inaccurate terminology.

On my Wordpress website I installed the Redux plugin. It has some cool features and I don't want to get rid of it, but I'm almost certain it's the source of my troubles. On my posts I'm using a Redux Template; that is when I'm in the Edit Post page, in Settings->Document->Post Attributes->Template I've chosen "Redux Contained" (although all Redux templates give me the same problem). With this template, comments don't appear on the posts. When I switch to "Default Template" they do, I just really don't like the format of the default template for my theme so I don't want to use it.

I'm basically asking for one of two solutions.

1. Has anybody solved this problem or a similar one with Redux or another template library? I see [someone](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/installed-redux-disable-the-submit-review-button-in-woocommerce/) had a similar issue before with Redux where installing it seemed to disable their WooCommerce Submit Review but it looks like it was another GDPR plugin that was the culprit (a plugin I don't have).
2. Are there any plugins that enable me to add a comment form as a block in the body of my post? I can have plugins for appointment calendars, payment forms, contact forms, everything under the sun that can be inserted as blocks in my post, but I can't find one for a comment form.

Comment: For help with the redux plugin you need to contact their support, 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is not in this stacks scope and offtopic here, as is asking for recommendations